# Can I get a userscript's version and use it on another webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, version-control, tampermonkey

So I know you can get the userscript's version info and use it as a variable in the userscript like so...

```
// @version      1.2.1
// @grant        GM_info

var version = GM_info.script.version;
console.log(`${version}`); // 1.2.1
```

I thought I could be able to use that variable on a different webpage. In this case, I want to display whatever the latest version is on the installation instructions page so that it says something to the effect of "Script name v.1.2.1"

I have a tag on my page (install.html) like this

```
<td>Script Name v.<span id="version"></span></td>
```

I have the userscript linked using a script tag on the install.html page (this may be the reason this isn't working):

```
<script src="Scripts/scriptName.user.js"></script>
```

with a line of code

```
document.getElementById("version").innerText=`${version}`;
```

What am I doing wrong, or is this even possible.

Note: I want this to work even if the person doesn't have the userscript installed yet.

Comment: TBH, I looked over that, and am completely clueless as to what's going on there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can show userscript data on a webpage provided that either the webpage, or your hosting server, can see and `GET` the script (possibly cross-domain).

But `<script src="Scripts/scriptName.user.js">` won't work, because:

1. It reads in and runs the script as vanilla javascript.  There's no way for you to read the source code or the comments where the script's metadata lurks.
2. Many script hosts, like GitHub, won't serve the file to a `<script>` tag at all (CORS blocked).  Or, some do, but send the wrong mime type.
3. **Tampermonkey can't fire for `<script>` nodes**, and it would be a major security disaster if it could.
4. So obviously, `GM_info` will not be available.
5. In fact, if the script uses any Tampermonkey native ***functions*** it will crash even if it loads.  Note that this doesn't mean the metadata.  That's harmless by itself.
6. Ditto if `@require` or `@resource` assets are needed. (And not independently loaded by the page.)

#### You must read in the userscript as *text*, and then parse the string for the version info.

For example, for [**this userscript**](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, Add kbd, sup, and sub shortcuts
...
// @version     4.2
...
```

The following code will get the version:

```js
$.get ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/BrockA/SE-misc/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js", scrptTxt => {
    var versionMtch = scrptTxt.match (/\/\/\s+@version\s+([0-9.]+)/i);
    if (versionMtch  &&  versionMtch.length > 1) {
        console.log ("The script is version: ", versionMtch[1]);
    }
    else {
        console.log ("Version metadata not found.");
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or HTML you can put at the end of your web page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready ( () => {
        $.get ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/BrockA/SE-misc/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js"
            , scrptTxt => {
            var versionMtch = scrptTxt.match (/\/\/\s+@version\s+([0-9.]+)/i);
            if (versionMtch  &&  versionMtch.length > 1) {
                console.log ("The script is version: ", versionMtch[1]);
            }
            else {
                console.log ("Version metadata not found.");
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: so to be clear, my web page needs to link jquery. and I run $.get on that page?

Comment: So, the fact that I use //@grant GM_info would break this as stated in number 5?

Comment: @Pshock13, the grant itself wouldn't break a `<script>`, it just sees it as a comment (which your page can't see).  As for the `$.get` and jQ:  Short answer is **yes**.  Long answer is that you could do ajax in vanilla.js, but it's not a productive use of your or my time, and it's beyond the scope of this question. ... Finally, those numbered bullet points apply to the `<script>` approach, not the `$.get()` approach.

Comment: Ok so do I put `<script src=jQ>$.get</script>` at the end of my install.html page?

Comment: Copied exactly what you have there, worked fine, logged the version. Put my file location in and got `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https:/.../Scripts/scriptName.user.js. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)` (I edited the actual address here)

Comment: @Pshock13, I did mention that that was a requirement in the very first sentence.  This question is answered.  Your additional [tag-on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) were answered.  Additional CORS issues are: (1) out of scope for the question you asked here, (2) already addressed in scores of other SO questions, and (3) impossible to walk you through since you have not provided the necessary details for that.  Mark this Q&A solved, then research the CORS issue.  Any new questions on that must include a [mcve].